# Uniform Approximation of analytic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, approximation-theory, weierstrass-approximation

For $\mathbb{D}=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1 \},$ it is well known that every function analytic in $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on the closure of $\mathbb{D}$ can be uniformly approximated by a sequence of rational (in fact polynomials) functions whose poles lies outside the closure of $\mathbb{D}.$ One easy proof is to use the uniform continuity and the Taylor series representation.

I know that the similar statement holds for functions analytic in an annulus $\mathbb{A}=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: r<|z|<R \}$ and continuous on the closure of $\mathbb{A} \ i.e.$  any function which is analytic in $\mathbb{A}$ and continuous on the closure of $\mathbb{A}$ can be uniformly approximated by a sequence of rational functions whose poles lies outside the closure of $\mathbb{A}.$

Is there any simpler proof of the statement that does not use results like Mergelyan’s theorem or Bishop localization lemma? I tried using Runge’s theorem but since the analyticity is given on only in the interior of $\mathbb{A},$ one can’t use the Runge’s theorem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about using the Laurent series and cutting it off at $\pm n$; this gives rational functions with poles at zero

Comment: @Conrad The Laurent series doesn't have to converge on the boundary, in which case the truncated Laurent series can't approximate uniformly on the annulus. I would look instead at $\sum_n c_n z^n e^{-n^2 \epsilon}$ (convolution with a periodized Gaussian on the circle)

Comment: @reuns - yes of course you are right as in the disc case one cannot use Taylor sums directly, but the idea was to split $f=g+h$ where $g$ is analytic in the outer disc (continuos on the external boundary) and $h$ analytic in the inner disc exterior (continuos on the inner boundary) and proceed like in the disc case - use the Caesaro sums for the analytic part as those converge on the boundary too and then do same on the inner boundary with a change of variables $z \to 1/z$ and find an appropriate combination of the negative part of the laurent series that converges uniformly there

Comment: Thanks!! I got the idea.